# How do I grab information from multiple pages using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am currently trying to get the titles from all auction lots (page 1 till page 33) of the 'Hong Kong Watches 2.0' auction provided on the Bonhams website (https://www.bonhams.com/auctions/25281/?category=results#/!). I am new to using python and selenium, but I tried to get the results using the code below. This code gives me the results I want, but only for page 1. Then, the code keeps repeating the results of page 1 over and over again. It looks like the loop to click on the next pages is not working. Can anybody help me with fixing this loop?

Below you can find the code I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.bonhams.com/auctions/25281/?category=results#/!')

while True:
    next_page_btn =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='lots']/div[2]/div[5]/div/a[10]/div")
    if len(next_page_btn) <1:
        print("no more pages left")
        break
    else:
        titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='firstLine']")
        titles = [title.text for title in titles]
        print(titles)

    element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'lots')))
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    element.click()
```

Below you find the output I get. Python keeps repeating/loading in this output over and over again (I think it does this 33 times???).

```
['Hong Kong Watches 2.0', '', 'OMEGA. A Very Fine And Rare Limited Edition 
Yellow Gold Chronograph Bracelet Watch, Commemorating the Apollo 11 Space 
Mission And The Successful Moon Landing in 1969', '', '', '', 'ROLEX. TWO 
SETS OF SHOWCASE DISPLAYS, MADE FOR ROLEX RETAILERS IN 1970s', '', 'ROLEX. 
TWO SETS OF RARE SHOWCASE DISPLAYS, MADE FOR ROLEX RETAILERS IN 1980s', 
'', 'PATEK PHILIPPE. A SET OF THREE RARE LIMOGES PORCELAIN AND ENAMEL 
DISHES', '', 'Bvlgari/MAUBOUSSIN. TWO SETS OF CUFFLINKS', '', 
'BOUCHERON/MONTBLANC. TWO SETS OF CUFFLINKS', '', 'PATEK PHILIPPE. TWO 
SETS OF CUFFLINKS', '', 'Jaeger-LeCoultre. A Gilt Brass Table Clock With 
8-Days Power Reserve and Alarm', '', 'Cartier & LeCoultre. A group of 
three gilt brass table clocks (Alarm/Alarm Worldtime/Engraved dial)', '', 
'Jaeger-LeCoultre. A Gilt Brass Table Clock With 8-Days Power Reserve', 
'', 'Reuge. A Gold Plated Musical Automaton Open Face Pocket Watch with 
Alarm', '', 'Imhof. An Attractive Gilt Brass Table Clock With Polychrome 
Enamel Dial', '', 'Vacheron Constantin. A Large Polished Metal Perpetual 
Calendar Wall Clock']
['Hong Kong Watches 2.0', '', 'OMEGA. A Very Fine And Rare Limited Edition 
Yellow Gold Chronograph Bracelet Watch, Commemorating the Apollo 11 Space 
Mission And The Successful Moon Landing in 1969', '', '', '', 'ROLEX. TWO 
SETS OF SHOWCASE DISPLAYS, MADE FOR ROLEX RETAILERS IN 1970s', '', 'ROLEX. 
TWO SETS OF RARE SHOWCASE DISPLAYS, MADE FOR ROLEX RETAILERS IN 1980s', 
'', 'PATEK PHILIPPE. A SET OF THREE RARE LIMOGES PORCELAIN AND ENAMEL 
DISHES', '', 'Bvlgari/MAUBOUSSIN. TWO SETS OF CUFFLINKS', '', 
'BOUCHERON/MONTBLANC. TWO SETS OF CUFFLINKS', '', 'PATEK PHILIPPE. TWO 
SETS OF CUFFLINKS', '', 'Jaeger-LeCoultre. A Gilt Brass Table Clock With 
8-Days Power Reserve and Alarm', '', 'Cartier & LeCoultre. A group of 
three gilt brass table clocks (Alarm/Alarm Worldtime/Engraved dial)', '', 
'Jaeger-LeCoultre. A Gilt Brass Table Clock With 8-Days Power Reserve', 
'', 'Reuge. A Gold Plated Musical Automaton Open Face Pocket Watch with 
Alarm', '', 'Imhof. An Attractive Gilt Brass Table Clock With Polychrome 
Enamel Dial', '', 'Vacheron Constantin. A Large Polished Metal Perpetual 
Calendar Wall Clock']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not required `selenium` library to **scrape** data. you can also get all pages data using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` library.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0",
       "Accept": "application/json"
   }

page_num = 1
title_list = []

while True:
    url = 'https://www.bonhams.com/api/v1/lots/25281/?category=results&length=12&minimal=false&page={}'.format(page_num)
    print("===url===",url)
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
    max_lot = response['max_lot']
    last_iSaleLotNo = 0
    titles = []
    for lot in response['lots']:
        last_iSaleLotNo = lot['lot_id_combined']
        title = BeautifulSoup(lot['styled_title'], 'lxml').find("div",{'class':'firstLine'}).text.strip()
        titles.append(title)

    title_list.append(titles)
    print("===titles===",titles)
    if int(max_lot) == int(last_iSaleLotNo):
        break

    page_num+=1

print(title_list)
```

First-page o/p:

```
['ROLEX. TWO SETS OF SHOWCASE DISPLAYS, MADE FOR ROLEX RETAILERS IN 1970s', 'ROLEX. TWO SETS OF RARE SHOWCASE DISPLAYS, MADE FOR ROLEX RETAILERS IN 1980s', 'PATEK PHILIPPE. A SET OF THREE RARE LIMOGES PORCELAIN AND ENAMEL DISHES', 'Bvlgari/MAUBOUSSIN. TWO SETS OF CUFFLINKS', 'BOUCHERON/MONTBLANC. TWO SETS OF CUFFLINKS', 'PATEK PHILIPPE. TWO SETS OF CUFFLINKS', 'Jaeger-LeCoultre. A Gilt Brass Table Clock With 8-Days Power Reserve and Alarm', 'Cartier & LeCoultre. A group of three gilt brass table clocks (Alarm/Alarm Worldtime/Engraved dial)', 'Jaeger-LeCoultre. A Gilt Brass Table Clock With 8-Days Power Reserve', 'Reuge. A Gold Plated Musical Automaton Open Face Pocket Watch with Alarm', 'Imhof. An Attractive Gilt Brass Table Clock With Polychrome Enamel Dial', 'Vacheron Constantin. A Large Polished Metal Perpetual Calendar Wall Clock']
```

Open the browser network tab and click on the next button, you will see JSON response data like
[image]

Comment: Hey bharatk, thank you for your quick response. However, when I copy this code into terminal it does not give me any output. I get this at the end of my code: 

`...         titles.append(title)
... 
    title_list.append(titles)
    if max_lot == last_iSaleLotNo:
        break

    page_num+=1

print(title_list)`

It does nothing. Does this have anything to do with indentation? Or should I change my user agent code line?

As I said, I am new to Python so my apologies if this is a fairly dumb question.

Comment: @B.vandenBoomen Updated my answer with a print statement, now you will see, there are total 32 pages and  it's getting data one by one.

Comment: The print statement works. However, I remain with the same issue. It prints only the titles of the first page and it keeps printing these titles. I want it to skip to the next page and grab the titles from that page and then skip to the next one.

Comment: @B.vandenBoomen I also update if condition `if int(max_lot) == int(last_iSaleLotNo):`

Comment: I just changed something and now it runs perfectly! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't understand someone down vote my answer without any comment or explanation. If not agree with my answer should comment here.

Comment: I don't know who did this. I am very happy with your clear answer. Thanks!